# Screen goes all noisy. Possible bug in Lollipop?

Tags: android, textures, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an app which does some really strange thing on Lollipop (never occured on other versions). Sometimes the screen textures just go crazy. It looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etgi59raqjyo0iw/scr.png?dl=0). In fact there should be pretty standard toolbar and list with two items in it (rows have Switch on the right side). Instead whole screen looks like a broken analog TV. There is not anything suspicious in the log. It is all OK when I restart the application. This bug occurs "randomly" in approximately 1 in 50 runs of the app.

Have you ever seen anything similar ? Can it be some bug in Android ?

Comment: looks cool though ;) May be something wrong with GPU? are you working with open-gl?

Comment: I saw an Android TV dev-preview-hardware running final 5.0 software doing the same thing. Interesting thing, it was only doing on one TV of my place, I switched to the other TV and the issue was gone. Very weird for sure, and it does sounds like something broken on Lollipop.

Comment: No open-gl, only really basic SDK stuff.

Comment: I have seen this screen when you are having some bad fragment management. Yes, it also occurred really rarely. In my case happened on KitKat N5, on HTC devices I got purely black screen.

Comment: This is not the case of a bad fragment management, because no fragments are ivolved.

Comment: Please file a bug on the [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) and include, at the very least, reproduction steps, a bug report, screenshot. If possible, include a minimal project that reproduces the issue. Thanks!